# Jekyll template, A Feeling Responsive, can't build by "jekyll build --watch"

Tags: ruby, jekyll

I am getting used to build a simple website through many templates. My final personal website will use A Feeling Responsive GH Pages template. And I had run into a error.

My own research pointed to a new feature in macOS called SIP. I could not install many dependencies to get this build successfully. I will include a snipet of the error here so that you guys can help me out.

```
Tos-MacBook-Pro:my-example-site duongnguyen$ jekyll build --watch
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in



`require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:34:in `require_from_bundler'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jekyll-3.2.1/exe/jekyll:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Have you tried `sudo gem install bundler` ?

Comment: I did without sudo. And there was no warning error at all. It's that a problem.

Comment: If I am right after `sudo install bundler`, I have made a mess in my system-wide ruby. Now, I abandon my macOS ruby and start reading about Docker container. I will come back to fix my macOS Ruby later. is this a good strategy? my first lesson in stack overflow, do check the profile before try on my own computer.

Comment: Yeah ! if you have a virtualization for ruby and you are not using the system one, it's fine. But, do have a knowledge about what virtualization you have used like `rbenv` or `rvm`.

Comment: I used rbenv and the warning is my original post. After sudo bundler I got a different warning. This time bundler has not found the gem that template needed to run.

Comment: Try `bundle install` and then `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Comment: If you have rbenv and installed ruby from rbenv, you don't need to use sudo. sudo helps save the gems for your system ruby. use `bundle exec` before each command if you are getting errors. P.S. The `bundler` gem also has to be installed from the ruby installed from `rbenv` like `bundle install bundler`, then only the bundle command will work for the ruby installed from rbenv.

Comment: Thank tGeek and David. it works like a charm.

Comment: My last question in this topic is that why I can't use `bundle exec Jekyll serve` in another theme, the warning is that no gemfile available. In the template, it has something to make the different result.